# Merging sheets daily macro

Tags: excel, vba

Good morning,

I'm using excel daily in my workplace and have a very basic understanding of macros but im hoping for your help as i am struggling to import the data correctly as the file is a 'daily log' of activities from a vessel (ship) and imported into a master sheet.

The problem is that the daily log is different everyday, the format is the same but sometimes spaces are on different rows of the excel file.

I'm looking for a macro that will import the data to the master sheet but that can interpret the data and be aware of the differences in the sheet daily.

Am i asking too much?

thanks in advance,

i have a basic function that imports the cell into the master file and copies the data but does not interpret the variances in the form daily.
[Final place data should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBv3C.png)
[Source data to take from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2Hhj.png)

Comment: Welcome. please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) . Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Have you considered using Excel's Power Query? It's highly effective at addressing many challenges associated with importing raw data. If Power Query doesn't provide the solution, then delving into VBA/macros might be the next step. The key is to identify a consistent element, like a timestamp or a specific number format, to help with the data extraction. If you can share a segment of your daily log, it would aid in offering a more tailored recommendation.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot (or two) of some sample data?

Comment: I have updated the main body of text with 2 screenshots - hopefully it'll assist you @TehDrunkSailor.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general solution to what (I think) you're trying to do.  You have some data that's not necessarily formatted as a continuous range.  You want to copy this data, while ignoring the "blanks" to another location.

Here is my sample setup:

[image]

So, we want to look at the data in the Daily Log section, copy it over to the Master Log section, and ignore those two blank rows (5 and 6).

Here's the code that will handle that **for this specific case**.  (You will need to edit it a bit to make it work for your case, of course.)

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SaveDailyToMaster()

    ' Copy the daily log info to the master log
    ' Do not include any rows that do not have a Trip number
    
    ' This range is selected by the user
    Dim dailyRange As Range
    Set dailyRange = Selection
    
    ' Store the information in the daily log in an array
    Dim dailyInfoAll() As Variant
    dailyInfoAll = dailyRange.Value
    
    ' Look through the daily info
    ' If the row has a value in the Trip column, store the info
    ' Otherwise, ignore the row
    Dim dailyInfoClean() As Variant
    ReDim dailyInfoClean(LBound(dailyInfoAll, 1) To UBound(dailyInfoAll, 1), LBound(dailyInfoAll, 2) To UBound(dailyInfoAll, 2))
    
    Dim row As Long, column As Long, rowClean As Long
    rowClean = 1
    For row = LBound(dailyInfoAll, 1) To UBound(dailyInfoAll, 1)
    
        If dailyInfoAll(row, 1) <> "" Then
            
            ' The first column of the row is not empty
            ' Add this data to the Clean array
            For column = LBound(dailyInfoAll, 2) To UBound(dailyInfoAll, 2)
            
                dailyInfoClean(rowClean, column) = dailyInfoAll(row, column)
            
            Next column
            rowClean = rowClean + 1
        End If
    
    Next row
    
    Dim masterRange As Range
    Set masterRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E3:G" & 3 + rowClean)
    masterRange.Value = dailyInfoClean
    
End Sub
```

First, the user selects the entire range of data with the Daily Log info.  Then, once the `Sub` runs, it takes this selected range of cells and stores them in an array.  We do this for a couple of reasons.  The major reason is that VBA (and Excel) work much faster with Arrays than Ranges.  Basically, you can think of an Array as a copy of the Range's data that the VBA code references.

Next, the code looks at each row in the array, and checks if the first value of the row (the "Trip" value) is empty.  If it is empty, it ignores this row and moves on to the next one.  If it is not empty, it stores this row's information in a new array, `dailyInfoClean`.

After it has looked at all rows in the daily log, it writes all of the info to the Master Log area of the sheet.